# Code for bar graph in android

Tags: android, graph

Can anyone help me coding a bar graph in android?

I tried running the sample code of http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/

But that sample is too big to just retrieve a bar code example from it.
Can any one suggest me any good website or documentation with detailed information for coding a graph in android? I need to show changes in the graph after frequent intervals.

Can anyone help me who has tried this before?

Comment: What's your specific issue? Drawing rectangles is fairly simple.

Comment: @StefanHållén hi i have some some doubts in same bar graphs can you please help me.

Comment: Post a separate, and properly formulated, question.

Answer (score 1):

There have been a lot of graph library threads on SO, you should have a look at them and try the different ones out.

I listed a few here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156740/im-looking-for-fancy-charts-library-for-android/5157576#5157576

Personally I would recommend using Steemas library - they have a lot of experience creating graphing libraries which is definitely shown in the API. The evaluation version can be found here:

http://www.steema.com/download/mobile

If you want to create a Bar graph with Steemas library here's a very simple example of doing so:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.steema.teechart.TChart;
import com.steema.teechart.styles.Bar;

public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TChart chart = new TChart(this);
        Bar exampleBar = new Bar();

        double[] exampleValues = {1,5,8,2.5,-3.3,10.75};

        exampleBar.add(exampleValues);

        chart.addSeries(exampleBar);

        setContentView(chart);
    }
}
```

Just some of the observations I got from using the library:

```
TeeChart info:
    Disable 3D:         chart.getAspect().setView3D(false);
    Disable Legend:     chart.getLegend().setVisible(false);
    Disable footer:     chart.getFooter().setVisible(false);
    Disable header:     chart.getHeader().setVisible(false);

How to set marks to data value instead of cylinder number?
    For a Bar data-set: bar.getMarks().setStyle(MarksStyle.VALUE);

How to move the marks closer to the chart rectangle?
    bar.getMarks().setArrowLength(5); - or negative values to put them on top of the bar

Different styles:
    bar.setBarStyle(BarStyle.RECTANGLE);

How do I make the lines thicker in a graph?
    line.getLinePen().setWidth(5); works, but it will change the width of the Legend as well.

How do I change the color of labels on axes?
    chart.getAxes().getLeft().getLabels().getFont().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    chart.getAxes().getBottom().getLabels().getFont().setColor(Color.WHITE);


SOLVED WORKAROUND - How do I set the background color of the chart itself? Tried so far (the TChart methods that take a Color from the TChart Color class, not the View methods) - only managed to make the 'surrounding' area black.
        chart.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        chart.getCanvas().setBackColor(Color.BLACK);
        chart.getGraphics3D().setBackColor(Color.BLACK);
            ---> WORKAROUND: Use the setBackground above, then use: chart.getWalls().getBack().setVisible(false); --- setColor() on walls is bugged?


How to choose the bounds of a chart manually?
    chart.getAxes().getLeft().setAutomatic(false);
    chart.getAxes().getLeft().setMinMax(-2, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

[here Source Code For any Chart in android](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) and
[link 2](https://github.com/hdodenhof/achartengine/blob/master/src/org/achartengine/chart/PieChart.java)

AChartEngine is a charting library for Android applications. It currently supports the following chart types:

- line chart
- area chart
- scatter chart
- time chart
- bar chart
- pie chart
- bubble chart
- doughnut chart
- range (high-low) bar chart
- dial chart / gauge

**combined (any combination of line, cubic line, scatter, bar, range bar, bubble) chart
cubic line chart**

Answer (score 1):

Go through [This Click Here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-drawing-bar-chart-using-achartengine/)  and enjoy the code, Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For Simple Bar chart You can use this code may be this solve your problem

1. Firstly you add achartengine-1.1.0.jar in your lib folder
2. then you declare in manifest

   ```
   <activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity"/>
   ```

create class:

```
    package com.example.barchartexample;    
    import java.net.Proxy.Type;
    import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
    import org.achartengine.model.CategorySeries;
    import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
    import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
    import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;

    public class BarGraph {
        public Intent getIntent(Context context){
        int y[]={25,10,15,20};
        CategorySeries series= new CategorySeries("BAR 1");
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            series.add("Bar"+(i+1),y[i]);

        }
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset= new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 5.5d);
        renderer.setLineWidth((float) 10.5d);


        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer= new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Simple Chart");
        mRenderer.setYTitle("Rupee");
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setShowGrid(true);
        mRenderer.setBarSpacing(.5);
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMax(5);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(50);
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1,"Income");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2,"Saving");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3,"Expenditure");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4,"NetIncome");
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true,true);
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer,org.achartengine.chart.BarChart.Type.DEFAULT);

        return intent;

       }    
    }


    package com.example.barchartexample;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       Button but;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        but=(Button)findViewById(R.id.BarGraph);
        but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                BarGraph bar = new BarGraph();
                Intent barIntent= bar.getIntent(MainActivity.this);
                startActivity(barIntent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a minimal chart library i suggest this one (this version it's a fork of Daniel Nadeau's library): https://github.com/Androguide/HoloGraphLibrary. It's very simple to use.

Here the original library: https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary